# TypeError at / save() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, database, typeerror

I cannot update the balance amount, when I try to save the value, it raises that error.

models.py,

```
class balance_data(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_amount = models.FloatField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

Views.py,

```
def cash_in(request, amount):

    new_amount = request.user.balance_data.total_amount + amount

    balance_data.total_amount = new_amount
    balance_data.save()

    return HttpResponse(request.user.balance_data.total_amount)
```

How can I solve this?

I am expecting to update the amount.

Comment: Please provide full error traceback

Comment: Try this.

balance_data.save()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried balance_data.save() but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Views.py

```
def cash_in(request, amount):
    # user whose total_amount is to be updated.
    user = request.user

    # get current user instance of balance_data
    user_current_balance = balance_data.objects.get(user=user)

    # update total_amount by adding amount to its total_amount
    user_current_balance.total_amount = user_current_balance.total_amount + amount

    # save changes to database
    user_current_balance.save()
    return HttpResponse(user_current_balance.total_amount)
```

Comment: It would be good if you add some context about what was wrong etc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You were not querying the database for obtaining and updating the total_amount field (see line in your question code). First you have to obtain an instance of balance_data for current user and then get specific fields and update them.